# Android: App not working on some rooted devices... Why?

Tags: android

I have an app on the market that is for rooted devices only. I have tested the app extensively on a rooted and unrooted G1, MT3G and Cliq with no errors. I am receiving a number of low ratings from people with supposedly rooted devices, saying that the app tells them that they are not rooted (of course, they usually don't leave important info like what phone and what rom)

Here is the code that generates the error... can anyone see out what the problem might be?

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.******);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String command1 = "mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system";
                String command2 = "cp -f /sdcard/******* /etc/";
                String command3 = "dos2unix -u /etc/*****";
                String command4 = "mount -o ro,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system";

                execCommandLine1(command1);
                execCommandLine1(command2);
                execCommandLine1(command3);
                execCommandLine1(command4);
}



void execCommandLine1(String command)
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

        try
        {
            proc = runtime.exec("su");
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
            osw.write(command);
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {

            Log.e("execCommandLine()", "Command resulted in an IO Exception: " + command);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (osw != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    osw.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e){}
            }
        }

        try 
        {
            proc.waitFor();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e){}

        if (proc.exitValue() != 0)
        {
            **// Error Dialog that is being erroneously displayed**

        }
        else {

               // Success Dialog
        }

    }
```

Comment: And the error is...what?

Comment: I imagine certain devices may not have their `/system` filesystem at `/dev/block/mtdblock3`, or they don't come with `dos2unix` installed or in the path.

Comment: @CommonsWare My error dialog is being displayed on some rooted devices... indicating that (proc.exitValue() != 0) which shouldn't happen on a rooted phone, unless something is wrong with my commands or the way that I am executing them

Comment: might this work for a mount command: grep " /system " /proc/mounts | awk '{system("mount -o rw,remount -t "$3" "$1" "$2)}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Christopher's comment: you appear to be making some assumptions:

- `/system` is at `/dev/block/mtdblock3`
- /`dev/block/mtdblock3` is `yaffs2`
- `/etc/` is a hardlink or symlink to something on `/system`
- `mount` exists
- `dos2unix` exists
- `cp` exists
- `su` exists

Most of those should be testable at runtime, though the `/etc/` check might be a bit tricky. Test that stuff out on the first run of your app, then do whatever makes sense:

- an "sorry, this app won't work" if you detect a failure
- disable the menu/button/whatever that leads to whatever is executing your code

Comment: I found this command floating around the internet... it is supposed to mount the appropriate mount point and fs: grep " /system " /proc/mounts | awk '{system("mount -o rw,remount -t "$3" "$1" "$2)}' However it does not seem to be working... any suggestions?

Comment: @Frank Bozzo: FWIW, I see neither `awk` nor `grep` on my emulator. However, bear in mind that you have this whole programming language called "Java" at your disposal. :-) Read in that file and parse it in Java to determine what you need.

Comment: nevermind... i figured it out using busybox (which is on almost all rooted roms) thanks for all the help!